# Disable bamboo script task when env condition is met

Tags: java, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I want one of deployment tasks to be `enabled(false)` only for `${bamboo.forge.environment.key} = test` environment in my bamboo specs config or entire step be skipped if condition is met.

Unfortunately, I'm not Java experienced thus any help will be appreciated.

From [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs/6.6.1/com/atlassian/bamboo/specs/builders/task/ScriptTask.html) it seems that `ScriptTask` inherits `conditions` method from `Task` but from there I got stuck...

```
    private static ScriptTask runStepFunctions() {
    return new ScriptTask()
            .description("Run Step Function")
            .inlineBody(
                "set -x \n" +
                ....
            )
            .environmentVariables("...")
            .enabled(false)
            .conditions();
}
```

[image]
[image]

In the end, task should look as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be Java expert to find correct snippet for Bamboo plan or deployment configuration. You can configure everything at UI and then use Export to Java Specs or Export to YAML Specs button at deployment project actions button to see how your configuration is translated into code. Then use generated snippet at your Java code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Oleksiy:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/exporting-existing-plan-configurations-to-bamboo-specs-894743917.html

Generated code:

```
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.condition.AnyTaskCondition;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.builders.AtlassianModule;
import com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.util.MapBuilder;

//add below method to ScriptTask()
.conditions(new AnyTaskCondition(new AtlassianModule("com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-conditional-tasks:variableCondition"))
                            .configuration(new MapBuilder()
                                    .put("variable", "${forge.environment.key}")
                                    .put("operation", "not_equals")
                                    .put("value", "test")
                                    .build()))
```